Como añadir un marcador en un mapa de google maps en un proyecto de angular 17
estoy creando mi primera aplicación web en Angular 17.
Tengo el mapa de Google funcionando y ahora quiero añadir un marcador en el mapa señalando el sitio concreto. No encuentro la manera de hacerlo, veo muchos tutoriales que hacen las cosas de formas diferentes y ninguno funciona o han hecho las cosas de forma diferente (supongo que para otra version de Angular). Veo que hay tantos tutoriales, como versiones de Angular. Ni siquiera Copilot me da la solución adecuada.
Tengo el script en el head:
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="API"></script>

En app.module.ts:
import { GoogleMapsModule } from '@angular/google-maps';

y
imports: [
    GoogleMapsModule,
]

en nosotros.component.ts:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-nosotros',
  templateUrl: './nosotros.component.html',
  styleUrl: './nosotros.component.css'
})
export class NosotrosComponent implements OnInit {
    
  constructor() {}
    
  ngOnInit(): void {}

  

  display:any;
  
  center: google.maps.LatLngLiteral = {
      lat: 999999,
      lng: -99999
      };


  zoom = 15;
}

y en nosotros.component.html:
<google-map height="450px"
            width="650px"
            [center]="center"
            [zoom]="zoom"
>

</google-map>

Version:
Angular CLI: 17.2.2
Node: 20.12.0
Package Manager: npm 10.5.1
OS: win32 x64
El mapa me aparece, pero ¿De que manera puedo poner un marcador y una ventana con el nombre del lugar en las coordenadas que quiero para señalar el sitio exacto dentro del mapa?
Muchas gracias.

Quizás esto te pueda ayudar MapMarker

Probado en Angular 16.2.11, debería de funcionar en Angular 17, pero tendrías que reemplazar <map-marker> por <map-advanced-marker>, aquí te explica como hacer la migración
index.html
<head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AQUI_VA_TU_API_KEY"></script>
</head>

Modulo
imports: [ /* Otros modulos */, GoogleMapsModule];

Componente
La ubicación es el Zócalo de la Ciudad de México.
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleMap, MapInfoWindow, MapMarker } from '@angular/google-maps';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
})
export class MapComponent {

  @ViewChild(MapInfoWindow) infoWindow: MapInfoWindow = {} as MapInfoWindow;

  coords = {
    lat: 19.4326018,
    lng: -99.1332049,
  };

  options: google.maps.MapOptions = {
    center: { ...this.coords },
    zoom: 15,
  };

  openInfoWindow(marker: MapMarker) {
    this.infoWindow.open(marker);
  }
}

HTML
<google-map height="300px" width="550px" [options]="options">
  <map-marker
    #marker="mapMarker"
    [position]="coords"
    (mapClick)="openInfoWindow(marker)"
  />
  <map-info-window>
    <div>
      <h3>Plaza Constitución</h3>
      <p>{{ coords.lat }}, {{ coords.lng }}</p>
    </div>
  </map-info-window>
</google-map>

Resultado

Documentación:
MapInfoWindow

